# ReCreating The Netflix Hover A Movie Functionality

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

If you goto the netflix site and hover over a movie http://www.netflix.com/BrowseSelection

You get a nice popup box that displays the movie info in it. My guess is this is done somehow with jquery and ajax. Does anyone know where I can find a code example of this functionaliity? Basically I want a nice popup and when the user hovers over a picture I query a database for info to fill the popup with.

I still need an example that kinda shows ajax calls and how they work.I am using .net, do I create a function in the code behind that accepts a querystring and returns data from the database, then call it though the ajax get method? I dont have a good understanding how to set all of this up?

Where do I get the fancy popup look?

Also, when I hover over a picture how can I come up with a way to get an id off that picture on a hover to send to the function that is gonna get the info about that picture from the db??

Comment: "do I create a function in the code behind that accepts a querystring and returns data from the database, then call it though the ajax get method?" Actually it sounds like you do have a good understanding how to set all of this up :) That's pretty much what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the source on the site.  Use a nifty tool like FireBug in FireFox to look at all the .js and .css files that go with it.  The Netflix site is your code sample.